# Calculate all possible sums of all summands in 4 columns in R

Tags: sum, rstudio

I have 4 columns of different sizes (eg column 1: 96 rows, column 2: 36 rows; column 3: 12 rows; column 4: 401 rows)

I am now looking for a function that allows me to calculate all possible sums of these 4 summands.
So at the end i need to have 96*36*12*401= 16630272 summs as a result in a data frame or vector or array to make a histogramm with ggplot.

I tried solve it with a for case that did not work:

```
r = 1
for(i in 1:(length(df$column1))) { 
  for(j in 1:(length(df$column2))) {
  for(h in 1:(length(df$column3))){
     for(k in 1:(length(df$column4))) {
        (i+j)-> a
        r = r +1
        }
}
}
```

Does someone have an idea how to solve this problem? Or does anyone have an idea why my code does not work? It has problems by storing my results in variable a and second problem it produces somehow way to much sums. (More than 16630272)
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your real column1/2/3/4 are probably not columns in a single data frame - as those must be in uniform length. Anyway, if these are the true sizes the naive solution shouldn't hog an impossible amount of memory (~126M):

```
d <- expand.grid(column1, column2, column3, column4)
all.sums <- mapply(sum, d[[1]], d[[2]], d[[3]], d[[4]])
```